# CORS не видит headers

Tags: python, backend, cors, fastapi

Делаю запрос через клиента:

```
static async getUserByToken(token) {
        const response = await fetch(
            config.backendUrl + '/account',
            {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                    'api': config.apiKey,
                }
            }
        )
        return await response.json()
    }
```

Без проверки api ключа всё работает, как я посмотрел в ответе из даже нету.

Проверка api:

```
   @app.middleware('http')
async def check_api_key(request: Request, call_next):
    if not DEBUG:
        api_key = request.headers.get('api')
        if api_key is None:
            return JSONResponse('API NEED TO BE SET',
                                status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        async with async_session_maker() as session:
            stmt = select(ApiKey).filter(ApiKey.key == api_key)
            scalars = await session.scalars(stmt)
            if scalars.first() is None:
                return JSONResponse('WRONG API KEY',
                                    status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

Ответ:

```
<bound method Headers.keys of Headers({'host': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'accept': '*/*', 'origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.15', 'referer': 'http://localhost:3000/', 'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty', 'accept-language': 'ru'})>
```

Настройка middleware:

```
origins = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_methods=['*'],
    allow_headers=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
)
```